# How to compare two dictionaries in python and replace the values accordingly?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, dictionary

This is the first dictionary:

```
[{'ITEMNO': None}, {'ITEM_TYPE': None}, {'CASE_QYT': None}, {'MIN_MINMAX_QUANTITY': None}, {'MAX_MINMAX_QUANTITY': None}, {'ONHAND': None}, {'ONHAND_SUBINV': None}, {'LOCATOR': None}, {'ORGANIZATION_ID': None}, {'INVENTORY_ITEM_ID': None}, {'CREATION_DATA': None}, {'INVENTORY_ITEM_STATUS_CODE': None}]
```

This dictionary contains all the key elements with value as None. I have a second dictionary which may contain all the key elements which are in the first dictionary or less than that but with the same key elements. I want to compare these both dictionaries and replace the value of None by the value element of the second dictionary if the keys are same. The second dictionary is as follows:

```
[{'ITEM_TYPE': 'SPR_ITEM_CPR'}, {'MIN_MINMAX_QUANTITY': '2'}, {'MAX_MINMAX_QUANTITY': '3'}, {'ONHAND': '162'}, {'ONHAND_SUBINV': 'RSP-SPARES'}, {'LOCATOR': '.RJG005D'}, {'ORGANIZATION_ID': '300000002445681'}, {'INVENTORY_ITEM_ID': '100000001537040'}, {'CREATION_DATE': '01-08-17'}, {'INVENTORY_ITEM_FLAG': 'Y'}, {'INVENTORY_ITEM_STATUS_CODE': 'Active'}]
```

The result dictionary should look like this:

```
[{'ITEMNO': None}, {'ITEM_TYPE': 'SPR_ITEM_CPR'}, {'CASE_QTY': None}, {'MIN_MINMAX_QUANTITY': '2'}, {'MAX_MINMAX_QUANTITY': '3'}, {'ONHAND': '162'}, {'ONHAND_SUBINV': 'RSP-SPARES'}, {'LOCATOR': '.RJG005D'}, {'ORGANIZATION_ID': '300000002445681'}, {'INVENTORY_ITEM_ID': '100000001537040'}, {'CREATION_DATE': '01-08-17'}, {'INVENTORY_ITEM_FLAG': 'Y'}, {'INVENTORY_ITEM_STATUS_CODE': 'Active'}]
```

Comment: You have a list of dictionaries, not a dictionaries. Is it right?

Comment: yes its a list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try converting l2 to a dictionary and then form required output.

**Ex:**

```
l1 = [{'ITEMNO': None}, {'ITEM_TYPE': None}, {'CASE_QYT': None}, {'MIN_MINMAX_QUANTITY': None}, {'MAX_MINMAX_QUANTITY': None}, {'ONHAND': None}, {'ONHAND_SUBINV': None}, {'LOCATOR': None}, {'ORGANIZATION_ID': None}, {'INVENTORY_ITEM_ID': None}, {'CREATION_DATA': None}, {'INVENTORY_ITEM_STATUS_CODE': None}]
l2 = [{'ITEM_TYPE': 'SPR_ITEM_CPR'}, {'MIN_MINMAX_QUANTITY': '2'}, {'MAX_MINMAX_QUANTITY': '3'}, {'ONHAND': '162'}, {'ONHAND_SUBINV': 'RSP-SPARES'}, {'LOCATOR': '.RJG005D'}, {'ORGANIZATION_ID': '300000002445681'}, {'INVENTORY_ITEM_ID': '100000001537040'}, {'CREATION_DATE': '01-08-17'}, {'INVENTORY_ITEM_FLAG': 'Y'}, {'INVENTORY_ITEM_STATUS_CODE': 'Active'}]

check_val = dict((i.keys()[0], i.values()[0]) for i in l2)
result = [{i.keys()[0]: check_val.get(i.keys()[0])} for i in l1 ]
print(result)
```

*Python3*

```
check_val = dict((list(i.keys())[0], list(i.values())[0]) for i in l2)
result = [{list(i.keys())[0]: check_val.get(list(i.keys())[0])} for i in l1 ]
```

**Output:**

```
[{'ITEMNO': None},
 {'ITEM_TYPE': 'SPR_ITEM_CPR'},
 {'CASE_QYT': None},
 {'MIN_MINMAX_QUANTITY': '2'},
 {'MAX_MINMAX_QUANTITY': '3'},
 {'ONHAND': '162'},
 {'ONHAND_SUBINV': 'RSP-SPARES'},
 {'LOCATOR': '.RJG005D'},
 {'ORGANIZATION_ID': '300000002445681'},
 {'INVENTORY_ITEM_ID': '100000001537040'},
 {'CREATION_DATA': None},
 {'INVENTORY_ITEM_STATUS_CODE': 'Active'}]
```

Comment: `dict.keys` and similar methods (like `dict.items`) do not support indexing

Comment: @natonomo. Thanks. Edited ans for py3

Answer (score 1):

With the original dictionaries as `dict1` and `dict2` the new one can be created in one line using [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) as follows:

```
new_dict = {k: dict2.get(k, v) for k, v in dict1.items()}
```

Or, because you know the default value in `dict1` is `None`, you could just use the keys:

```
new_dict = {k: dict2.get(k, None) for k in dict1}
```

Or if you don't care about mutating `dict1`:

```
dict1.update(dict2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the two dictionaries as `dict1`(`None` values) and `dict2`(meaningful values) you can `update` `dict1` as:

```
dict1.update(dict2)
```

As other answers have pointed out, please note that you do not have a `dict`, you have a `list` of `dict`s, and you will need to make a dict first, which you can do as:

```
a_var = [{1 : None}, {2 : 'b'}]
dict1 =  {x.keys()[0]: x.values()[0] for x in a_var}
```

Once you have that:

```
dict2 = {1 : 'a', 2 : 'bb', 3 : 'c'}
dict1.update(dict2)

print(dict1)
```

Output:

```
{1: 'a', 2: 'bb', 3: 'c'}
```